# Can not find action on server due to wrong url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am on the Url `localhost:555/Configuration/Addresses`

I have a form with 3 buttons Edit/Create/Delete.

When I press one of the buttons the form action is dynamically set depending on the value attribute of the button. I use localized buttons later.

When I click a button and check the source code in the browser I get this url:

'Configuration/Addresses/Edit' and submit the form.

Why do I then see in the url this: 
`'Configuration/Configuration/Addresses/Edit'`

Therefore the Edit action on server is not found :/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="form-group required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, HtmlAttributes.Label)
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Title)
                          .BindTo(Model.Addresses.OrderBy(order => order.Text))
                          .HtmlAttributes(HtmlAttributes.KendoControl))
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default addresses-btn" name="action" value="Delete">Delete</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default addresses-btn" name="action" value="Edit">Edit</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default addresses-btn" name="action" value="Add">Create</button>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".btn-default").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).closest("form");
            var action = $(this).val();
            $(form).attr('action', '@MVC.Configuration.Name' + '/' + '@MVC.Configuration.Addresses.Name' + "/" + action);
            $(form).submit();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: because you need a forward slash `$(form).attr('action', '/' + '@MVC.Configuration.Name' ....`

Comment: There are relative and absolute url's.In your case the url is relative, you don't need '@MVC.Configuration.Name' + '/' + part (you are already in the address controller). If you add '~' in the beginning you will have an absolute url.

Comment: @Url.Content("~") + "\" + action did not work then I get add or edit in the url

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks yours worked! Make an answer its shorter than Albertos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perpend a forward slash to the generated url

```
$(form).attr('action', '/' + '@MVC.Configuration.Name' + '/' + '@MVC.Configuration.Addresses.Name' + "/" + action);
```

Comment: Thanks again for your enduring help!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the path provided is appended to the current URL.

You need to redefine it. Try:

```
$(form).attr('action', "@Url.Content("~")@MVC.Configuration.Name/@MVC.Configuration.Addresses.Name/" + action);
```

Let me know if this works.

Alberto

Comment: this would give you '~Configuration/Addresses/Edit' which is again wrong

Comment: @JitendraPancholi That's not true. It gives "/Configuration/Addresses/Edit" which is correct. Please check Url.Content("~") behaviour....

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Actually Albertos answer worked! although he mixed a single/double quote and the start/end of the end. I had to correct it.

Comment: @Pascal yeah you're right. I updated it. If you want you can mark as answer to cover the -1

Comment: @JitendraPancholi edited ;) you can remove your -1 if you still believe it is correct :)